# Alignment in form-horizontal using bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Actually i m new on bootstrap,I am using form-horizontal for creating my layout responsive.
my code:

```
<div class="panel-body">
              <form class="form-horizontal" role="form">
    <div class="form-group">

        <div class="col-md-2">
            <label for="" class="control-label">From:</label>
            <div id="date_dropdown" ></div>
        <div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="" class="control-label">To:</label>
        <div id="date_dropdown1" ></div>
        </div>
    <div class="col-md-2">
        <label for="" class="control-label">Dept:</label>
        <div id="dept_dropdown" ></div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-2">
         <label for="" class=" control-label">Factory:</label>
        <div id="factory_dropdown" ></div>
        </div>
            <div class="col-md-4">
         <label for="" class=" control-label">BatchType:</label>
        <div id="batch_dropdown" ></div>

         </div>
     </div>

</form>
```

In this code i am having two date picker and 3 select drop down and value will be coming from database.so i want all element should be align in one line according to device it will be adjustable ..can u some one help me how i can resolve ..

Comment: if i use span2 class then it will be breakdown to all the element in separate row..but my requirement is it will be breakdown in next row according to device?

Comment: how you want? can you draw a image..

Comment: like this way http://www.bootply.com/4kqqwbkhtw

Comment: @shri:Thanks a lot for your suitable reply.i want From: also should comes in same row as like To:.,Dept ...etc ..all the column in same line and adjust  automatically according the screen.

Comment: @thanks a lot user1234 Finally i have solved my issues